# Upload document with lookup column programmatically

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I have a Document Library, with a lookup column referencing a row of a metadata list (custom).

I am trying to upload documents programmatically but I also want to add a row in this list and link it to the document that is just uploaded. How can I achieve this?

```
public static void Upload(string path)
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://localhost/"))
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                var folder = web.GetFolder("Documents");
                var files = folder.Files;

                var fStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(path);
                var contents = new byte[fStream.Length];
                fStream.Read(contents, 0, (int)fStream.Length);
                fStream.Close();

                SPList list = web.Lists["Documents Data"];
                SPListItem listItem = list.AddItem();
                // ....
                listItem["Title"] = "test test";

                listItem.Update();

                var documentMetadata = new System.Collections.Hashtable { { "Data", listItem } };


                // .... ??
     }
```

Comment: Do you need a second list for the metadata? Document libraries can have additional columns (or preferably a content type) to hold the metadata.

Comment: Yes, i actually do a second and a third list to store metadata to create some kind of relational database with lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example demonstrates how to:

- create a list item in `DocumentsMetadata` list
- upload file into `Documents` library and set it properties, in
  particular set Lookup field value to newly created item from `DocumentsMetadata` list

Example:

```
using (var site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
{
    using (var web = site.OpenWeb())
    {

       //1.Create meta item
       var metaList = web.Lists.TryGetList("DocumentsMetadata");
       var listItem = metaList.AddItem();
       listItem["Title"] = "Documents info";
       listItem.Update();

       //2. upload file and set properties
       var list = web.Lists.TryGetList("Documents");
       var fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
       var fileUrl = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
       var fileProperties = new Hashtable();
       fileProperties["Metadata"] = listItem.ID;  //set Metadata Lookup Id 
       var uploadFile = list.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileUrl, fileContent, fileProperties, true);

   }
}
```

**Update**

```
using (var site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
{
    using (var web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
                var list = web.Lists.TryGetList("Documents");
                var metaList = web.Lists.TryGetList("DocumentsMetadata");
                var fileUrl = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
                var file = web.GetFile(SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(list.RootFolder.Url, fileUrl));
                var fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
                var refItemId = -1;

                if (file.Exists)
                {
                    //retrieve existing meta item 
                    var refLookupVal =  new SPFieldLookupValue(file.ListItemAllFields["Metadata"].ToString());
                    refItemId = refLookupVal.LookupId;
                    var listItem = metaList.GetItemById(refItemId);
                    //...
                    listItem.Update();
                }
                else  /* New one? */
                {
                    //Create meta item
                    var listItem = metaList.AddItem();
                    listItem["Title"] = "Documents info";
                    listItem.Update();
                    refItemId = listItem.ID;
                }

                //upload file and set properties
                var fileProperties = new Hashtable();
                fileProperties["Metadata"] = refItemId; //set Metadata Lookup Id 
                var uploadFile = list.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileUrl, fileContent, fileProperties, true);


   }
}
```

Comment: I am trying it right now.

Comment: This works fine, but if I upload programically the same document twice, it will not update its metadata list item, but i will always add a new item instead and link it to the document.

Comment: See the updated answer, it demonstrates how to handle the case if file **already exists**

Answer (score 1):

You just need to loop through all documents in that Library and get the latest document using order by in caml query like below after **fStream.Close()**.

Code sample for caml query

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.ViewXml =
       @"<View>
           <Query>
                <OrderBy><FieldRef Name="Modified" /></OrderBy>
            </Query>
       </View>"; 
   ListItemCollection listItems = spList.GetItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.Load(listItems); 
   clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Now you can loop through all the items & get the first item which is recently uploaded & get the URL by

```
SPListItem item = ...;
string absUrl = (string) item[SPBuiltInFieldId.EncodedAbsUrl];
```

Now you can use

```
Hashtable MetaData = new Hashtable();
MetaData = retornaMetadata(MetaData);
SPFileCollection destFiles = web.GetFolder("Folder Path").Files;

Files.Add(Path.GetFileName(inputFile.PostedFile.FileName), inputFile.PostedFile.InputStream, MetaData, true);

private Hashtable retornaMetadata(Hashtable MetaData)
{
  MetaData.Add("Column Name", "Metadata Value");
  return MetaData;
}
```

Comment: Is it safe? What if many users are uploading documents at the same time?

Comment: As your code itself uploading document than there is no chance of conflict of time of upload. we are going to upload the document & get that document information instantly.

Comment: Have you got any resolution?

Comment: I am not convinced that there is absolutely **no chance** of time conflict, as the same code will be executed by many users in the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code snippet to create a new file (add to folder)

```
SPFile spfile = spfolder.Files.Add("Sample.docx", fileStream, true);
spFile.Item["Title"] = "Sample document";
spFile.Item.Update();
```

In this case you will get the item id through

```
spFile.Item.Id;
```

Comment: How does this answer my question?

Comment: Now you have the ID of newly uploaded file so you can add it as a lookup to item in the list.